# IOS 7 - Update an UILabel with value computed in background using delegation

Tags: xcode, multithreading, uilabel

I am having a problem trying to update UILabel.text using a value calculate in background using delegation (which seems to be slow).

```
@interface BTAViewController : UIViewController <ExchangeFetcherManagerDelegate>

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bidPriceLabel;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) FetcherManager *fetcherManager;

@end
```

my BTAViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fetcherManager = [[FetcherManager alloc]init];
    double calculateValue = [self.fetcherManager fetchPricesFor]; 

    self.bidPriceLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    [self.bidPriceLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    self.bidPriceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", calculateValue];
 }];
```

The label has been correctly initialised in a method not shown here and it shows the correct default value at startup. Once I execute this code, the label will get the value 0.00000000, because my calculateValue has not been calculate yet.

How can I wait for this value to be calculated and then display it has text of the label ?

I can't post images because I don't have enough reputation...

Thanks

Comment: `double calculateValue = [self.fetcherManager fetchPricesFor];` is a synchronous request which tries updating the label afterwards. Can you post what `fetchPricesFor` does briefly?

Comment: Thanks Koray for the answer ! [self.fetcherManager fetchPricesFor] does an httpRquest to a website and obtains some values back. I want to display one of this value in the label text, but the value takes around 3-4 seconds to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value calculated is not purely 0 or null?

What I would do is to add a delegate callback function in BTAViewController.m from FetchManager

Something like this:

```
BTAViewController.h
//add delegate callback function under @interface
-(void)valueReturned:(float)someValue;



BTAViewController.m

-(void)valueReturned:(float)someValue{
//updates value when the delegate returns the value
    self.bidPriceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", calculateValue];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.fetcherManager = [[FetcherManager alloc]init];
    self.fetchManager.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.fetchManager getPricesFor];

   // double calculateValue = [self.fetcherManager fetchPricesFor]; 

    self.bidPriceLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    [self.bidPriceLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bidPriceLabel];
}];
```

In FetchManager.h and .m

```
FetcherManager.h

@property (retain,nonatomic)id<ExchangeFetcherManagerDeelgate>delegate;
-(void)getPricesFor;



FetcherManager.m
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)getPricesFor{
    float price;
    //calculate price
    [self.delegate valueReturned:price];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer but I have already tried that and It did not work. The value is definitely different from zero at the end of the program, but it takes some time to be calculated because It does a rest request to a website.  So, when you execute [self.delegate valueReturned:price]; price as still the old value, which is 0.00000. After a couple of seconds price will have the right value which is 123.2546 but It won't be displayed in the label because "self.bidPriceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", calculateValue];" has already been executed !

Comment: Are you saying the price is calculated on a server? If so, then call [self.delegate valueReturned:price]; after the value is returned from the server such as in connectionDidFinishLoading. Otherwise, where does the calculated price shown? You could replace [self.delegate valueReturned:price] with NSLog() of where the price is shown.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer.So basically [self.fetchManager getPricesFor]; will make an httpreq and get a JSON as a response. A soon as that comes back I will call [self.delegate didReceiveValue:calculatedvalue]; in my fetcherManager.m. THE PROBLEM is that while this delegation is happening, the BTAViewController.m will go further, with self.bidPriceLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", calculatedValue]; but the calculatedValue is still zero when the controller calls this method, because the delegation takes time to happen.What I want is to WAIT FOR THE DELEG TO FINISH.

Answer (score 0):

Add the label to the view, set it to be hidden (`bidPriceLabel.hidden = YES`). Then, create and add a method for the delegate (BTAViewController) which when fired, checks the `hidden` property of the `UILabel`, and if it is `TRUE` (is hidden), set **bidPriceLabel.hidden = NO** which will then display the UILabel as you intended to.

Call this method in `FetchManager` once you are done retrieving the information.

Comment: That sounds like an hack... I need to display the labels as soon as I create them, but I need to display the new value as soon as I calculate them. There has to be a way...

Comment: @Sinapse  oh not a problem at all, then in the delegate method, say updateLabel:(NSString*)newValue (which you call from the FetchManager on its delegate), implement a simple change to the label's text property to display the new string...

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks for the answer. That would definitely work but I can't do it because I need to call [self.delegate valueReturned:price]; in a for cycle in the BTAController.m, before I can update the label value. Thus, the method [self.delegate didReceiveValue:calculatedvalue]; is called several time, which means I can update the label value here, neither I can in the BTAController.m after the for loop, because there the values are not calculated yet ...